# How do I test a function which has API call inside it?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I am trying to Unit test a function that calls another API inside it. Here is my Class.

```dart
class TelehealthController extends GetxController {
  final RxBool loadingDetails = true.obs;
  TelehealthController();
  TelehealthsClient physician = Get.put(TelehealthsClient(Dio()));

  late TelehealthResponse details;
  late List<TelehealthData>? datadetails = details.data;

  int? get id => details.data!.first.physicianId;
  String get telehealth =>
      details.data!.first.defaulttelehealthinstructions.toString();

  @override
  void onInit() async {
    super.onInit();
    //Here each API call needs to Initialize
    await fetchTelehealthDetail();
  }

  Future<TelehealthResponse> fetchTelehealthDetail() async {
    loadingDetails.value = true;
    final response = await physician.getTelehealthData(); //mock
    loadingDetails.value = false;
    details = TelehealthResponse(data: response);
    int count = details.data!.length;
    loadingDetails.value = false;
    return details;
  }
```

I am trying to Unit test `fetchTelehealthDetail` function which calls `physician.getTelehealthData()` API which returns data as a Future. As far as know about testing, any calls to the external API or Databases should be mocked. However, I cannot mock the `physician.getTelehealthData()` because as soon as I call controller.fetchTelehealthDetail() the real API gets called.

Is there any workaround on how I can achieve it and also achieve the Code Coverage result. Due to the problem, I could not test the getter values like `id` and `telehealth`.

I tried to mock the whole `TelehealthController` class and create a mock response of `fetchTelehealthDetail` but that approach does not cover the Code-Coverage. I wonder if there is any workaround for testing this piece of code.

As per @lepsh request, I  have added the Mocks in my test file. Below is my testfile:

```dart
class MockTelehealthClients extends Mock implements TelehealthsClient {}

class MockTelehealthController extends Mock implements TelehealthController {}

void main() async {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  List<TelehealthData> _listofMockTelehealthData = [
    TelehealthData(
        physicianId: 12345,
        defaulttelehealthinstructions:
            "At the time of your appointment, click this link to join your video visit: https://zoom.us/j/a-random-zoom-link"),
    TelehealthData(
        physicianId: 890,
        defaulttelehealthinstructions:
            "At the time of your appointment, click this link to join your video visit: https://zoom.us/another-zoom-link"),
  ];
  var _telehealthResponse = TelehealthResponse(data: _listofMockTelehealthData);
  var _mockTelehealthClient = MockTelehealthClients();
  var sut = TelehealthController();
  var _mockTelehealthController = MockTelehealthController();


//mocking using Mocktail
 when(() => _mockTelehealthClient.getTelehealthData()).thenAnswer(
        (invocation) => Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () async {
              return _listofMockTelehealthData;
            }));

    when((() => _mockTelehealthController.fetchTelehealthDetail()))
        .thenAnswer((invocation) {
      return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
        return _telehealthResponse;
      });
    });
```

The problem with this approach is that I can mock my API calls but when I run tools such as `flutter test --coverage` and generate the Code Coverage report, this doesn't include the above mocked API calls due to which I get only 4% of Code Coverage.

Comment: Have you heard of mocking? There are several mocking frameworks available which help you create dummy dependencies, here is an example : https://medium.com/codechai/mocking-http-request-in-flutter-c2596eea55f2 .

Comment: Welcome to SO! Would you please [edit] your question and add the test as well (The one where you tried to mock it)?

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar I have mocked my dependencies using the following method. I am new to Flutter/Dart and testing as a whole, so the method I've followed maybe wrong. Could you please tell me a better approach and the solution to the problem above ?

Comment: @lepsch I've added the following Unit test cases on my side using `Mocktail`.

Comment: @AmoghSarpotdar Any updates on how to carry the test here ?

Comment: @SanjaySanjel : Apologies, havent had a chance to look at this today. Will get back soon.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mockito](https://github.com/dart-lang/mockito) for mocked unit testing.

 For example:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:mockito/annotations.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

@GenerateMocks(TelehealthController)
void main() {
  group("TelehealthService", () {
    late TelehealthController mockTelehealthController;
    setUp(() {
      mockTelehealthController = MockTelehealthController();
    });
    test('fetchTelehealthDetail', () async {
      when(mockTelehealthController.fetchTelehealthDetail())
      .thenAnswer((_) => Future.value(TelehealthResponse());
      expect(mockTelehealthController.fetchTelehealthDetail(), 
      TelehealthResponse());
    }
  }
}
```